# Display Only Values not retrieved by array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<select>
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$q = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE duration='first lecture' and day='Sunday'";
$r = mysql_query($q); 
$ro = mysql_num_rows($r);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){

for ($i=1; $i<=14; $i++)
{
$exclude = array($row['name']);
if(in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
?>
<option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php
}
}
?>          
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use a FOR LOOP to eliminate elements retrieved by an array in one loop. Suppose $row retrieved some values , what I want with that FOR LOOP is to display numbers between 1 to 14 except the retrieved values .

I tried it many times and I succeed in that, but the loop in first time eliminate just first retrieved and in second time eliminate just second retrieved value.

Is there's a way to eliminate both at one time ?

Comment: What do you mean by "except the retrieved"? Where and how is this being set? DB?

Comment: suppose query retrieved values (4,5) i want to display numbers between 1-14 except (4,5)

Comment: OK got it give me a minute to reply.

Comment: is `$row['name']` a number? Why do you convert it into an array?

Comment: yes it's number , to eliminate it's values

Comment: mysqli_* functions to be used instead of already depreciated mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $row['name'] is a int and use the below code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
    $exclude[] = $row['name'];
}

for ($i=1; $i<=14; $i++)
{
  if(in_array($i, $exclude)) continue;
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Start using mysqli_* function. mysql_* functions are depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First off you should be using PHP PDO for db interactions, mysql_fetch_array has been deprecated. Here is a link to the PDO's manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

See answer bellow:

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE duration='first lecture' and day='Sunday'";
$stmt = $db_pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<select name="" id="">
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 14; $i++):?>
        <?php $good_to_go = true; ?>
        <?php foreach ($data as $exclude): ?>
            <?php if ($exclude['name'] == $i): ?>
               <?php  $good_to_go = false;?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ($good_to_go): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help!